# Solve $47x \equiv 4 \mod 17$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I don't really understand how to solve the equation $$47x \equiv 4  \mod 17.$$
If someone could help, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As $47\equiv-4\pmod{17},$

$$47x\equiv4\pmod{17}\iff-4x\equiv4$$

As $(4,17)=1,$

$$-x\equiv1\iff x\equiv-1$$

$$\implies x\equiv-1+17$$

Comment: Your last line is garbled...

Comment: @TonyK, Now sure if I have understood you correctly .

Comment: Well you've fixed it now, haven't you? Initially it read $x\equiv -+17$.